# Merge QuerySetValues object in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I working with Django 1.4 and Py 2.7 and I need to merge some QuerySetValues and sum the field "total".

My model is:

```
class CategoryAnswers(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category")
    answer = models.DecimalField("Resposta", default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, verbose_name="Brand")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category_answers'
        verbose_name = "CategoryAnswers"
        verbose_name_plural = "CategoryAnswers"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category.name 

class Answers(models.Model):
    category_answers = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryAnswers, verbose_name="CategoryAnswers")    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User")
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign,verbose_name="Campaign")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'answers'
        verbose_name = "Answers"
        verbose_name_plural = "Answers"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Answers'
```

When I search all records necessary to group the fields with the following code:

```
for answer in answers:
        print answer.category_answers.all().values('brand','category').annotate(total=Sum('answer'))
```

Return this:

```
[{'category': 7L, 'brand': 8L, 'total': Decimal('5.00')}, {'category': 3L, 'brand': 5L, 'total': Decimal('5.00')}, {'category': 4L, 'brand': 8L, 'total': Decimal('4.00')}, {'category': 2L, 'brand': 1L, 'total': Decimal('4.00')}, {'category': 4L, 'brand': 5L, 'total': Decimal('3.00')}]

[{'category': 7L, 'brand': 8L, 'total': Decimal('5.00')}, {'category': 3L, 'brand': 5L, 'total': Decimal('8.00')}, {'category': 4L, 'brand': 8L, 'total': Decimal('7.00')}, {'category': 2L, 'brand': 1L, 'total': Decimal('5.00')}, {'category': 4L, 'brand': 5L, 'total': Decimal('4.00')}]

[{'category': 7L, 'brand': 8L, 'total': Decimal('5.00')}, {'category': 3L, 'brand': 5L, 'total': Decimal('6.00')}, {'category': 4L, 'brand': 8L, 'total': Decimal('6.00')}, {'category': 2L, 'brand': 1L, 'total': Decimal('7.00')}, {'category': 4L, 'brand': 5L, 'total': Decimal('7.00')}]
```

I need to group by category and brand and sum the total for each of these fields. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
categories=CategoryAnswers.objects.values('category', 'brand').distinct()
for cat in categories:
    print CategoryAnswers.objects.filter(category=cat["category"], brand=cat["brand"]).values('category', 'brand').annotate(total=Sum('answer'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
categories=CategoryAnswers.objects.values_list('category', 'brand').distinct()

for cat in categories:
    print CategoryAnswers.objects.filter(
        category=cat.category, brand=cat.brand).annotate(total=Sum('answer'))
```

Comment: I changed some things but used as base your answer!